# Some users see HTML in email body after server changes

Tags: php, html, email, html-email, email-headers

Pair.net recently upgraded our PHP install and afterwards client started see HTML in email body where previously he had seen formatted email body.

I add myself as a CC and my Outlook shows me the formatted body but on the same email he sees code.

Anyone run into this before?

Any hints?

Code looks like:

```
$headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n" . 
    "Reply-To: $email\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(). 
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$msg = "<html><body><head><style type='text/css'>TD { font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial, Verdana; font-weight:bold; }</style></head>";
$msg .="<table width='98%' border='0' cellspacing='8'> etc etc etc

mail("$to, me@myoffice.com", $sub, $msg, $headers);
```

Actual email headers follow:

```
Delivered-To: xxx@xxx.com
Received: by 10.204.63.10 with SMTP id z10cs87437bkh;
        Wed, 8 Jun 2011 12:50:43 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.216.230.105 with SMTP id i83mr5392587weq.43.1307562643519;
        Wed, 08 Jun 2011 12:50:43 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <anonymous@tinco.pair.com>
Received: from tinco.pair.com (tinco.pair.com [209.68.1.91])
        by mx.google.com with SMTP id f69si2172888wes.55.2011.06.08.12.50.42;
        Wed, 08 Jun 2011 12:50:43 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of anonymous@tinco.pair.com designates 209.68.1.91 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.68.1.91;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of anonymous@tinco.pair.com designates 209.68.1.91 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=anonymous@tinco.pair.com
Received: (qmail 11613 invoked by uid 65534); 8 Jun 2011 19:50:41 -0000
Date: 8 Jun 2011 19:50:41 -0000
Message-ID: <20110608195041.11612.qmail@tinco.pair.com>
To: sales@yyy.com, xxx@xxx.com
Subject: WEBSITE BERG SELECTION FORM
From: David XXX <xxx@xxx.com>
Reply-To: xxx@xxx.com
X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.6MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continue to think server upgrades and switch to qmail may have done this but issue is resolved by switching to [SwiftMail](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score 1):

**Update (original below)**:

You forgot a newline in your headers ;)  Between the X-Mailer header and the MIME-Version header there should be an `\r\n`... it's swallowing the MIME-Version (in your eg headers too):

```
$headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n" . 
    "Reply-To: $email\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n".
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/html;charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
```

**Old (potential) answer**

I think this may be a case of... case, the correct header is:

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset="iso-8859-1"
```

There may also be a transfer-encoding issue (the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header)

Comment: Testing this now.  Thanks for reply!

Comment: The change did not alter what I see (good) or what client sees (code)